# Linq Query foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have the following Linq query (relating to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011)

```
var ContactDetails = Xrm.ContactSet
                .Join(Xrm.AccountSet, c => c.ParentCustomerId, a => a.ParentAccountId, (c, a) => new { c.Telephone1, c.Telephone2, c.Telephone3, c.MobilePhone, c.FullName, a.Name })
                .Where(c => (c.MobilePhone.Equals(CallerCli)) || (c.Telephone1.Equals(CallerCli)) ||
                    (c.Telephone2.Equals(CallerCli)) || (c.Telephone3.Equals(CallerCli)));

int Count = 0;

foreach (var c in ContactDetails)
{
     Count++;
}
```

However, when running the foreach I get the following exception on the first loop:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

This only happens when adding the `.Join` into the LINQ query, however searching SO I can't see anything similar (apologies if I missed something).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but when you do get the query sorted out, you can just do this: `var count = ContactDetails.Count();` instead of `foreach`-ing over the items.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon thanks Joe, the `Count` was more of an example, I do use it to pull data from the ContactDetails object (FullName, Name) however I couldn't even get the count to run! Appreciate the advice.

Comment: What are the types of `Xrm.ContactSet` and `Xrm.AccountSet`?  Are they just `IEnumerable`s or something more complex?